# Is there any way to get mouse/cursor icon on standard html elements

Tags: javascript, cursor, icons, mouse

Is there any way to determine what style or icon the mouse is when it is over a standard html element that does not have a css cursor style setting? For example the mouse icon changes from an arrow to a hand when it is over a standard html button, or from an arrow to a text input icon when it is over a standard text input.

This code only works if an element has a style.cursor setting.

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    //console.log("mouse is down")
     var x = event.clientX, y = event.clientY,
    elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
  console.log("element="+elementMouseIsOver+" cursor="+elementMouseIsOver.style.cursor)
    })
```

Is there another method to get the mouse icon for standard html items?

Comment: Have you tried `getComputedStyle()`? (Called from your mousemove event listener so that the cursor is actually the shape you're wondering about at the time.)

Comment: That actually works great! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

A trick may be like this :

```
var currentCursor = undefined;
$('*').mouseenter(function(){
    currentCursor = $(this).css('cursor') ;
});
```

OR without using `JQuery` would be:

```
var currentCursor = undefined;
addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
    if (e.target instanceof HTMLAnchorElement) {
        currentCursor = e.target.style.cursor;
    }
});
```

Comment: *"Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."* - from the [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) displayed when you hover the mouse over the "javascript" tag. (But if you feel you must recommend a solution relying on a library, at least mention *which* library.)